# Google Sheets - Using a cell's value in OFFSET in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm writing a macro script that uses the offset function:

e.g.
`spreadsheet.getRange('G2').offset(0,1).activate();`

But instead of it offsetting by a static number of columns I need it to offset by whatever number is shown in a particular cell (B29 in this case). How do I reference the value of B29 within the offset function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const bvalue =  spreadsheet.getRange('B29').getValue(); //get the value of B29
spreadsheet.getRange('G2').offset(0,bvalue).activate(); //pass it to the offset function
```

assuming always that `spreadsheet` is a [sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) which you already have defined.